# Centos change directory permissions

Tags: apache, centos, chown

Morning all,

I'm trying to give apache the write access to a particular folder for PHPDOCx.

```
[root@patdraft word2]# ll
total 4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 718 May 15  2014 generate.php
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   0 May 13 09:20 lib
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   0 May 13 09:41 output
[root@patdraft word2]# chown -R apache:apache output/
[root@patdraft word2]# ll
total 4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 718 May 15  2014 generate.php
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   0 May 13 09:20 lib
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   0 May 13 09:41 output
```

Any ideas why it's not changing the directory owner?

Thanks, Harry

Update:

I am using a directory in mount for my apache base dir.

```
[root@patdraft word2]# cat /etc/passwd | grep apache
apache:x:48:48:Apache:/var/www:/sbin/nologin    
[root@patdraft mnt]# ll
drwxr-xr-x  1 root   root    4096 Apr 25 16:21 patdraft
```

The phpdocx directory is inside of my web server directories.

Update 3:

```
[root@patdraft /]# chown -R apache:apache /mnt/patdraft/*
[root@patdraft /]# ll /mnt/patdraft/public_html/pages/word2/
total 4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 774 May 15 09:14 generate.php
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   0 May 13 09:20 lib
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   0 May 15 09:33 output
```

It's just not changing the owners?!

Update 4:

```
[root@patdraft word2]# egrep -iw --color=auto 'user|group' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd                                                                          .conf
User apache
Group apache
```

It's not because the group is spelled 'Apache' instead of 'apache'. Any more ideas?

Update 5:

This is my error log from httpd after restarting the service;

```
[Thu May 15 10:03:15 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.26] PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in /mnt/patdraft/public_html/pages/word2/generate.php on line 21
[Thu May 15 10:03:15 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.26] PHP Warning:  copy(/mnt/patdraft/public_html/pages/word2/output/output1400144595.docx): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /mnt/patdraft/public_html/pages/word2/lib/phpdocx/classes/CreateDocx.inc on line 5343
```

CreateDocx.inc, line 53

```
copy(
   $this->_tempFile,
   $fileName . '.' . $this->_extension
);
```

Update 6:

I am now mounting the ntfs share under the apache user to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Is this means that you have "PHPDOCx"  folder in  "/var/www" folder ?

Comment: It's in /mnt/patdraft/..../phpdocx/. I am using /mnt/patdraft as my /var/www.

Comment: try to go to root => "cd /" and after that make a commad "chown -R apache:Apache /mnt/patdraft/*"

Comment: With user/group as apache?

Comment: See updates 3 and 4, still no luck unfortunately.

Comment: Please restart httpd and try to access phpdocx. Please take a look at access.log of your httpd service

Comment: See update 5. That's what I've had all along, I just added the test create folder to see if I could create a directory, which I obviously can't. This makes no sense to me, why can't I successfully chown?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52732/discussion-between-max-and-harry-torry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was mounting with ntfs, and Windows(?) not allowing me to change permissions.

I edited my /etc/fstab mount point to add file_mode, and dir_mode as follows;

```
192.168.1.211:/APShared/IT/websites/patdraft.albright /mnt/patdraft cifs rw,username=<removed>,password=<removed>,noserverino,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0777,exec 48 48
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check in /etc/passwd if you have such user "apache".

Please check the permission on /var/www folder and provide the same permission on the PHPDOCx folder.

Please be sure that dont put the PHPDOCx folder in home folder of some user.

Comment: Updated OP answering to your comments!